# How to capture MySQL expensive slow queries for certain time period like 2 - 4 PM

Tags: performance, mysql-workbench, monitoring

I am just getting started to mysql, would like to know how to capture the mysql slow running queries between certain time period like between 2 PM - 4 PM. Having some timestamp column available for some table i am very confident this can be achieved. But lets say few of our tables doesn't have any timestamp column on it, in this case how we can apply the filter either in sys or performance schema to capture slow running queries across all the tables  for a particular time period like 2 - 4 PM. In this way it will help to just focus the DB Performance for a particular time period where we ran some load test rather looking all the history of data in mysql

This question is very similar to capture the AWR report in oracle for the particular test duration . Hope its clear

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a reversed way to solve problems. If you want to monitor performance you need to take a different approach than trying to load test or capture sql statements directly. Monitoring has evolved a lot since the 1990s when the AWR reporting was the right way to monitor performance of a database. Today we can monitor production in real-time and obviously in test/dev. You will see issues in prod you cannot recreate, so spending a lot of time trying to recreate environments and load is even more futile in nature than it was 10-20 years ago when we had more consistent workloads. This is especially the case as APIs have made our data visible to other new apps in very inconsistent ways:

- Monitor the application which is using the DB. Typically this is done with APM tools. The leaders can be found in the new 2016 Magic Quadrant for APM these include AppDynamics (where I work), Dynatrace, New Relic. These products will log all of the statements, code level performance, and even end user experience in production. You'll find the overhead different between each product. AppDynamics has always been production focused, overhead is under 3%.
- Monitor the database. This is something you would have done with OEM on Oracle, but the problem today is there are typically 6-12 common databases at a typical enterprise. None of the tools which support many platforms go as deep as the vendor tools, but many of the vendor tools, especially in the open source DB space are severely lacking (including MySQL). This is why we built AppDynamics for Databases which supports over 15 platforms now and is deployable SaaS or on-premises. Other good solutions for DB monitoring on mysql would include VividCortex (SaaS only) and SelectStar (New SaaS only product). Don't be fooled by those which collect metrics on the runtime, that's just a small part of what needs to be analyzed. There are jobs, queries, and other metadata which is critical.
- Monitor the infrastructure which the DB relies upon. This means capturing metrics from the network, storage, and server layers. If you want to go deeper there are performance monitoring tools for these, but often times they are not as necessary when you monitor the higher layers which include some of the server and storage metrics.

Good luck!